# Realtime push/pull with Django/Redis/Node.js

Tags: django, node.js, redis

I'm trying to add realtime updates on a Django app which has a similar architecture as explained here: http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2012/apr/23/ginger-tech-stack/. Basically, updates are send from Django to Node.js via Redis, then pushed to connected clients with Socket.io. Right now, I can broadcast to every clients connected but in a real case, I need to send data only to clients concerned by an action (e.g.: a user post a message, only his contacts/subscribers receive this message). So I need some kind of authentication on the Node.js side to know who's who. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Assuming Django and Node are on the same hostname, and you have cookie based authentication in Django, and thus, Node can read those cookies, you could write an adapter for Django's authentication, for Node.

Comment: Ok, so I moved from database-backed to cookie-based session and I can read the « sessionid » cookie on Node side. So now I guess I have to port [this fonction](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/signing.py#L134) to Node...

Comment: Sorry -- I wasn't clear on what I meant with cookie based auth: If you can access the same database from Node, you should be able to use db-backed sessions, I just meant using cookies for session IDs. Either solution should work fine. Yeah, [node's crypto module](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) will be your friend.

Comment: Well, when searching for a solution I thought accessing the db from Node.js would be over-complicated but it's probably much easier than using Django signed cookies. I'm going to try this way. Thanks for pointing out ;)

Comment: So now I can retrieve the session data from the db based on the cookie's session id. I thought the session data was base64 but it seems to be python specific (pickle - which I'm not familiar with)… Is there a way to decode this on node side ?

Comment: Ouch -- I didn't remember Django pickling the session. That's bad. No, it's a Python specific serialization. See my answer to the duplicate post (this gave me enough flashbacks to mark yours as duplicate).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing a session store on Redis for a Django and a Express.js Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391275/sharing-a-session-store-on-redis-for-a-django-and-a-express-js-application)

Comment: I found another [similar thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842738/pylons-beaker-json-encoded-sessions) as well but for Pylons/Beaker. Sounds good to me and should not be hard to port to Django…

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution so far to get the identity of the connected user in socket.io/node.js (if you have better solution, feel free to post):

**On Django side:**

- Patch Django to use json instead of pickle object to store session data:

  ```
      diff --git a/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py b/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py
  index 5a637e2..cb4db54 100644
  --- a/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py
  +++ b/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py
  @@ -2,9 +2,9 @@
   import time
   from datetime import datetime, timedelta
   try:
  -    import cPickle as pickle
  +    import json
   except ImportError:
  -    import pickle
  +    import simplejson as json

   from django.conf import settings
   from django.core.exceptions import SuspiciousOperation
  @@ -75,21 +75,21 @@ def _hash(self, value):
           return salted_hmac(key_salt, value).hexdigest()

       def encode(self, session_dict):
  -        "Returns the given session dictionary pickled and encoded as a string."
  -        pickled = pickle.dumps(session_dict, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  -        hash = self._hash(pickled)
  -        return base64.encodestring(hash + ":" + pickled)
  +        "Returns the given session dictionary as json and encoded as a string."
  +        data = json.dumps(session_dict)
  +        hash = self._hash(data)
  +        return base64.encodestring(hash + ":" + data)

       def decode(self, session_data):
           encoded_data = base64.decodestring(session_data)
           try:
               # could produce ValueError if there is no ':'
  -            hash, pickled = encoded_data.split(':', 1)
  -            expected_hash = self._hash(pickled)
  +            hash, data = encoded_data.split(':', 1)
  +            expected_hash = self._hash(data)
               if not constant_time_compare(hash, expected_hash):
                   raise SuspiciousOperation("Session data corrupted")
               else:
  -                return pickle.loads(pickled)
  +                return json.loads(data)
           except Exception:
               # ValueError, SuspiciousOperation, unpickling exceptions. If any of
               # these happen, just return an empty dictionary (an empty session).
  ```

**On Node.js side:**

- Read the session key from the "sessionid" cookie:

  ```
  socket.on('connection', function(client) {
      ...
      var cookie_string = client.handshake.headers.cookie;
      var parsed_cookies = connect.utils.parseCookie(cookie_string);
      var sessionid = parsed_cookies['sessionid'];
      ...
  });
  ```
- Retrieve & decode the session data from the db corresponding to the sessionid to get the user id.

Comment: Why patch Django when you could just write your own session backend?

Comment: Yep, probably better indeed. So I tried to extend Django db session backend: https://gist.github.com/9ef870e91dc034f60179 but it's not working properly. Not sure what's wrong... I can login, the cookie & db entry seem to be correctly created but when I'm accessing a login_required protected view I'm redirected to the login page...